# How to compute $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{\lambda^{2k}}{(k!)^2}$

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

This is my exercise

> Goals occur in a soccer game according to a Poisson Process. The average total number of goals scored in a 90-minute match is 2.68. Assume that two teams are evenly matched. Estimate the probability both teams will score the same number of goals.

And this is my attempt:

Assume that $X$ is the number of goals the first team score, and $Y$ is the number of goals the first team score. Since the two teams are evenly matched, then $X$ ~ Poiss(1.34) and $Y$  ~ Poiss(1.34) and they are independent. Then the probability that

\begin{align*}
P(X=Y) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty P(X=k).P(Y=k) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-1.34}1.34^k}{k!}\dfrac{e^{-1.34}1.34^k}{k!} = e^{-2.68}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{1.34^{2k}}{(k!)^2}
\end{align*}

Now I don't know how to compute the last series. Can somebody show me how to do so? Thank you.

Comment: see the 'exponential function' example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: But the denominator have the square there and I don't know how to deal with it...

Comment: If you need only the answer... a numerical evaluation will be an easy route. But it would be nice having a closed form solution in terms of $\lambda$, if that exists.

Comment: I think I can use this idea. Thank you!